# How can I implement lazy-loading in the ag-grid filebrowser layout?

Tags: file-browser, ag-grid

I see in this question:
[Create tree in angular-grid (ag-grid) with async data loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242276/create-tree-in-angular-grid-ag-grid-with-async-data-loading/37331178#37331178)

that Niall recommends writing a cellRenderer but I'm not sure how that would work.  I am guessing there would be a button in the cellRenderer that would trigger the call to get more data, but how would I rebind?

Answer (score 0):

adding rowData directly inside the component watched the updated rowData.

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" class="ag-theme-balham" 
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel"
  [rowData]="rowData">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Here's official [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)
[Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-more-details/)